# How do I browse the source code for a gem in Rails3 with RVM (linux & gedit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, gedit

I am running rails3 in Ubuntu and using gedit for coding. I am using RVM. To look at the gem source code I tried: `bundle open jquery-rails`

That doesn't work since I hadn't setup an editor. After setting gedit as the editor it still doesn't work because gedit can't be passed directories. I guess it only works with files. Too bad :(.

nathan.f77's answer to this question ( [Lookup Gem or Plugin code packaged in a Rails3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265154) ) seems promising, but I wasn't able to follow his instructions. They lacked sufficient detail for me.

**What is a very easy way to browse the source files for gems that I am using in my rails3 app?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CubaLibre's response got me half-way there. The other piece of the puzzle I was able to get from [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167818).

Here are the steps to browse gem code in gedit using Ubuntu.

a. From the command line run:

```
gnome-open $(bundle show [gem-name])
```

b. This will open up the gem directory in nautilus. From there just double click on file you'd like to see and it will open up in gedit.

Answer (score 12):

`bundle show jquery-rails` should tell you where the gem source lives on your filesystem. Then open the file that you want.

Comment: Ok. I'm close to figuring this out I think with this help. How do I get the output of that command to open up in nautilus? I tried: bundle show jquery-rails | gnome open. That doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @snowguy sorry i don't know anything about nautilus. I use a Mac and Rubymine for Ruby code, so i get 'jump to definition' for free. 

In your case, I would use emacs/vim and open individual files as i need them. You can explore generating a TAGS table with etags/ctags and using the http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JumpToDefinition operation in emacs as well! All the best.

Comment: The piping of commands in Ubuntu works as expected. You just have to use it the right way. Like in your example it should be `bundle show jquery-rails | xargs gnome-open`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a default editor set in your terminal, on MacOS you can do something like this example (atom is my editor, but should work with sublime or textmate, vim, etc.):

```
atom $(bundle show name_of_gem)
```