# Is there a way to pipe the results of bundle show jquery-rails into gnome-open?

Tags: command-line, terminal, bundler, pipe

I looked on several online help pages for using pipe in the linux command line but I wasn't able to get anything to work. My best guess as to what would work was the following:

```
bundle show jquery-rails | gnome-open
```

But it fails. If instead I run `bundle show jquery-rails` and then copy the results and then type `gnome-open` and then paste, it works fine.  Is there a way to combine this into a single step I can run from the command line?

*Background*

If you'd like to understand why I care, see this question: [How do I browse the source code for a gem in Rails3 with RVM (linux & gedit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546475)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was noted in the [question you posted on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167818/using-pipe-with-bundle-show-and-gnome-open), you need to use a subcommand.

```
gnome-open "$(bundle show jquery-rails)"
```